# How do I set vim as the external editor in FarManager, and pass full path names?

Tags: vim, far-manager

I'm trying to configure VIM as my external editor in the [far file manager](http://www.farmanager.com). I want to be able to select multiple items in a folder, some being directories, and have their **full paths** passed to the vim command line.

**Update:** To clarify exactly what I want to do. I want to be able to select multiple files in a panel like so:

[image: Far Manager Screen Capture]

and have vim opened like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\vim.exe"  c:\src\TalkMaterials "c:\src\abba 1.txt" "c:\src\abba 3.txt"
```

This would open all the files in different buffers.

Comment: Just to be sure: what are you trying to do: open a single file or several files selected files? `!@AFQ!` is about several selected files which names are written to a temp file X. Name X is sent to Vim in the command line. File X contains selected file names, quoted(!), I have just checked this. Everything looks right. So, what is wrong in your case?

Comment: At least give an example of a correct command line (what you want to get) and tell what you actually get from Far.

Comment: Perhaps it should be re-tagged to the existing tag `far-manager`.

Comment: A couple of solutions using batch files are proposed in here: http://forum.farmanager.com/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=5851

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution that does exactly what you are asking for. But it requires the plug-in FarNet and its module PowerShellFar:

http://code.google.com/p/farnet/

They also need .NET 2.0+ and Windows PowerShell 2.0 installed. This is already the case on Windows 7 but earlier Windows versions are not so lucky. Besides, PowerShell 2.0 is only for Windows XP SP 3 and above (not even SP 2).

If you are not yet scared then here is the trick. In the external editor command we call PowerShellFar through its command line prefix ">:"

```
>: & vim @(Get-FarPath -Selected) #
```

That's it. It works, I have tried it (not with vim, though, I do not have one). It is fast, it does not start PowerShell each time; the core is loaded once when Far starts.

Note: The last '#' in the command is a little PowerShellFar convention: to not add to the persistent command history commands with '#' in the end. This command is for opening the external editor, it is written once and we do not want it to pollute the history of other commands typed manually.

P.S. I am the author of both FarNet and PowerShellFar, just in case. They are open source, mature and robust. I would recommend them in any case, as far as you use Far Manager and recent Windows has all the prerequisites for these tools.

Comment: That is really useful. It won't work on my windows 2008 server since its not R2, but it works on all my workstations.

Answer (score 3):

The closest I can come is **vim !&** this creates the following command line

```
"C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\vim.exe"  TalkMaterials "abba 1.txt" "abba 3.txt"
```

That seems to work just fine, but I'd like full paths passed to vim anyway. Before accepting my own answer, I'd like to see if there is a way to pass all the full paths to vim.

Comment: Perhaps you should accept your own answer. According to the Far help there is no such a feature of "special symbols" as a list of full paths. Try to ask this question at the Far forum, I might miss something. Ask exactly about a list of full paths of several selected files.

Comment: I made a feature request for this in mantis http://bugs.farmanager.com/view.php?id=1585 and I did also ask on the forum. http://forum.farmanager.com/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=5851&p=71719#p71719